# Combination of two figures leaving right margin

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The image in my work is leaving the right margin, how to restrict them from moving out? The two images are fig_4 and fig_5 ; both are .tikz files in separate folder than the .main file.

**Code:**

```
\begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \input{figs/fig_4} % first figure itself
            \caption{Loss plots for the configuration 3Layers and 5 Neurons in each layer}
            \label{fig_l1}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
             \input{figs/fig_5} % second figure itself
            \caption{Loss plots for the configuration 5Layers and 3 Neurons in each layer}
            \label{fig_l2}
        \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

**Code (fig_5) right:**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
     xmin=0, xmax=1e+4,      % The output would not be visible 
     ymin=1e-4, ymax=1,  % The output would not be visible 
    xlabel={Number of Epochs}, 
    ylabel={Normalized MSE: $\log_{10} (e)$},
    label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
    tick label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
]
\addplot[scatter, no marks, draw=blue] table [x=Epochs, y=Test_loss, col sep=comma] {5N_3H.csv};
\addplot[scatter, no marks, draw=red] table [x=Epochs, y=Train_loss, col sep=comma] {5N_3H.csv};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Your images are too wide for your minipages. You can see that by looking at the non-centred captions. Make them smaller or show us a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz how to make them smaller? I have added the code of one of the images.

Comment: Please make a minimal reproducible example, starting with a class, the necessary packages and everything else needed to compile your document

Comment: You can specify the `width=\linewidth` in the axis keywords.  Easier than `scale=...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you did not provide a full MWE (e.g. we are missing your *.csv files, your documentclass and your (related) packages), so I'll have to use some sample data, but I tried to change your code as little as possible.

###### The bad option

You could wrap your figures into a `\resizebox` like `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{figs/fig_5}}`. This will scale the whole plot (including ticks, tick labels, axis labels, linewidths etc.) to `\linewidth` (or whatever value you put in the first argument). The cool thing is that you use exactly the space you have, the drawback is that you get inconsistent graphs and fonts, because they are scaled together with the rest.

###### The good option

Scale the plot, but leave everything else as it is: you can add `scale=<value>` to your axis, which will do exactly this. The only drawback is that you will have to choose the `<value>` manually.

###### The best option

If you use the "good" option, you will have to modify your `fig_5` file by hand, which is not a good idea if it is generated automatically (e.g. by Matlab2Tikz or similar). Therefore you can use `\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={scale=<value>}}` before you input your file. As it is inside a figure, this change will be a local one.

###### Code containing all options

```
\begin{filecontents*}{fig5.tex}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[
            xmin=0, xmax=1e+4, % The output would not be visible 
            ymin=1e-4, ymax=1, % The output would not be visible 
            xlabel={Number of Epochs}, 
            ylabel={Normalized MSE: $\log_{10} (e)$},
            label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
            tick label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
            % scale=0.8, % GOOD option
        ]
            \addplot[scatter, no marks, draw=blue] table [row sep=crcr] { 0  1 \\ 10000  0.0001\\};
            \addplot[scatter, no marks, draw=red ] table [row sep=crcr] { 0  1 \\ 10000  0.0001\\};
        \end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            %\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{fig5}} % BAD option
            \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={scale=0.8}}
            \input{fig5} % first figure itself
            \caption{Loss plots for the configuration 3 Layers and 5 Neurons in each layer}
            \label{fig_l1}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            %\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{fig5}} % BAD option
            \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={scale=0.8}} % BEST option
            \input{fig5} % second figure itself
            \caption{Loss plots for the configuration 5 Layers and 3 Neurons in each layer}
            \label{fig_l2}
        \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

###### Pretty screenshot

[image: Result]

Comment: Hey, thanks actually that works decently well!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to put the tikzpictures into separate files, why not use standalone?  Easier to debug and faster to use.

The tricky bit is that you need to use the same `\textwidth` in both files.  One way is to use the [class=...] option of standalone.  Plan B is to write `\the\textwidth` and manually set it in standalone.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% or [showframe] for geometry
\begin{document}

%\the\textwidth% plan B

\begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics{test5}% or fig/fig5 if set up that way
            \caption{Loss plots for the configuration 3Layers and 5 Neurons in each layer}
            \label{fig_l1}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics{test5}% or fig/fig5 if set up that way
            \caption{Loss plots for the configuration 5Layers and 3 Neurons in each layer}
            \label{fig_l2}
        \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Without the csv files and the narrow width, the resulting tikzpicture looks awful, but that is an aesthetics problem.

```
\documentclass[class=article]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%\setlength{\textwidth}{345pt}% plan B

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
     xmin=0, xmax=1e+4,      % The output would not be visible 
     ymin=1e-4, ymax=1,  % The output would not be visible 
    xlabel={Number of Epochs}, 
    ylabel={Normalized MSE: $\log_{10} (e)$},
    label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
    tick label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
    width=0.45\textwidth
]
\addplot[scatter, no marks, draw=blue] table [x=Epochs, y=Test_loss, col sep=comma] {5N_3H.csv};
\addplot[scatter, no marks, draw=red] table [x=Epochs, y=Train_loss, col sep=comma] {5N_3H.csv};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```